# Call API from Electron-Angular project by proxy config

Tags: angular, electron

On angular, the only thing to do is to create a `proxy.conf.json` file, to configure the proxy with the command `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json` and to write a text like

```
{
  "/api/v1/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Then the app will automatically call `http://localhost:3000` if I call in my app `http://localhost:4200/api/v1/...`

My issue is that my angular app is running like an Electron app, so the command I execute to run it is `electron .` and I don't even know how to tell Electron that I want to call the locahost 3000 if I call api/v1 in my app.

I've read the doc of Electron but I don't understand how to set the proxy with `setProxy()`.

The error I got when I try to call my API from the app is

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, if you had this issue too, there is no need to call the localhost of the angular project, you just need to call directly the API and it works.

For example,

```
this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:4200/api/v1/...').subscribe(...);
```

becomes

```
this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/...').subscribe(...);
```

Simply as this.